# error with google maps "opps something went wrong " - html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Still get the "Sorry! Something went wrong.
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details."   after I have entered the API key

<

```
!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
          /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
           * element that contains the map. */
          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
          /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
          var map;
          function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
              zoom: 8
            });
          }
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDli7-1WRjUXMACkIg7H9ZFNakF1wiOORo&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you just post your API key here?  Could your account be locked out?

Comment: no, i have not posted the API key here before, i have only posted it now as I don't know why i am still getting the opps error ...after the fact i have inserted the API key. any suggestions am i missing something?

Comment: I have just  checked you code with my API key and it works fine. check your api key or regenerate you api key form your account. Hope it helps...

Comment: i still get the same error i have regenerated a new key and tried serval web browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Wild Cards & IP's Have Issues

There seems to be a global issue currently when using restrictions that use Wildcards and IP's. If you are using an IP or a Wildcard, replace it with the actual domain name, without the wildcard or have no restrictions at all.

If you aren't restricting it, make sure your API is implemented correctly on the site and that you haven't reached your quota.

Comment: Is this still happening? Do you have any links for it? We're having this issue but only for a small amount of customers and can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: It's working on 2 of my sites, but it's still an issue on one clients website. I contacted them recently to ask them to try again with a new key. Once they've done that, I'll update this comment.

http://hairboutique.co.uk

Comment: Ours is just intermittent. Is that what you're noticing?